# 'tuple' object does not support item assignment in torch.cat()

Tags: python, pytorch, torch, bert-language-model

I am trying to use the torch.cat() to contenate the torch tensor. However, I face the error messagge with --> 'tuple' object does not support item assignment.

Here are my code:

```
inputs = tokenizer.encode_plus(txt, add_special_tokens=False, return_tensors="pt")
input_id_chunks = inputs["input_ids"][0].split(510)
mask_chunks = inputs["attention_mask"][0].split(510)

print(type(input_id_chunks))

for i in range(len(input_id_chunks)):
    print(type(input_id_chunks[i]))
    print(input_id_chunks[i])

    input_id_chunks[i] = torch.cat([
        torch.Tensor([101]), input_id_chunks[i], torch.Tensor([102])
    ])
```

The outputs looks fine, the inputs_id_chunks[i] is torch.Tensor:

`<class 'tuple'>

<class 'torch.Tensor'>`

But I got the following print and error message:

TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment

in torch.cat()

I have using the small testing code for torch.cat() and it works fine, but I don't know what is missing in my original codes.

Comment: you can not change tuple value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't change tuple value, instead you can assign it to list, then append new value to it and then after all changes you want to implement, you should assign again it to tuple.

please check this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_change_tuple_item.asp)

Comment: Thank you! the correct way to do it is turn `input_id_chunks` and `mask_chunks` into a list. `input_id_chunks, mask_chunks = list(input_id_chunks), list(mask_chunks)` and it works.

Answer (score 0):

to be more clear, `input_id_chunks` is a tuple:

```
input_id_chunks = inputs["input_ids"][0].split(510)
print(type(inputs_id_chunks)) # this is <class 'tuple'>
```

then in `for` loop you are assigning a tuple value

```
input_id_chunks[i] = torch.cat([
        torch.Tensor([101]), input_id_chunks[i], torch.Tensor([102])
    ])
```

that is why you are getting error.

```
input_id_chunks=list(input_id_chunks)
```